# Printing an InputStream in Logcat

Tags: android, inputstream

I want to print the InputStream in logcat(for testing/later I will use it), my current code is as follows.

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                InputStream in = null;
                int response = -1;

                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://any-website.com/search/users/sports+persons");
                URLConnection conn = null;
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
                conn = url.openConnection();

                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                    throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

                httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();

                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                }

                if (in != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, ">>>>>PRINTING<<<<<");
                    Log.e(TAG, in.toString());
                   // TODO: print 'in' from here
                }
                in.close();
                in = null;



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

But I am not able to do this, so please check the code and add/modify the code to do this.

Comment: what is your problem, Input Stream coming null? or Log.e doesnt work?

Comment: Read upon this article : http://excid3.com/blog/just-get-to-the-point/

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I read/convert an InputStream to a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Comment: Log.e working, i need to print the **in**

Comment: @Caner your link is useful... but surprisingly I havn't get it as a search result when I searched :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    try {
        return new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And in your code:

```
                Log.e(TAG, ">>>>>PRINTING<<<<<");
                Log.e(TAG, in.toString());
                Log.e(TAG, convertStreamToString(in));
```

Comment: maybe this solution may be helpful for somebody: http://shomeser.blogspot.com/2013/12/redirect-stream-to-logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `TAG` should be a constant like:

```
public final String TAG = YourActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

Then you would do something like:

```
Log.e(TAG, "You're message here:", e)
```

e is your error from print stack.

You also want to make sure you import the Log in the Android library.

Also, after looking at your code, you might want to surround your `httpConnection()` with  try/catch statement, that way you can catch the error, and put it in your Log file. You have the Log printing if your stream has something, or isn't null, but you want to know if you don't have a connection, and that would give you a null value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: oh... i just missed that, so i want to edit the part. actually that's not the problem...

Comment: Does this answer the question? and also to add, in Log I usually use `e.getmessage()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Just add this code to if(in != null):   

    byte[] reqBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int reqLen = 1024;
    int read = -1;

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((read = is.read(reqBuffer, 0, reqLen)) >= 0)
            result.append(new String(reqBuffer, 0, read));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


Log.d("TAG", result.toString());
```

Comment: nothing happened... let me check again, if unsuccessful then I will call you again

Comment: please make sure in != null, logcat is printing d logs and result != "". This code always worked for me